# I'm having trouble putting a TextBox & TextBlock inside a GroupBox in TabItem

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to put my Text Block & Text Box inside a Group box. These contents are in Tab Item tag.

I've tried change Group Box Grid setting but it wasn't working for me. Group box's position seems okay for me, but it shows only text box in my Group box.

```
<Tab Control>
            <Tab Item Header="Connection">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Column Definitions>
                        <Column Definition Width="20"/>
                        <Column Definition Width="auto"/>
                        <Column Definition Width="auto"/>
                        <Column Definition Width="*"/>
                        <Column Definition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.Column Definitions>
                    <Grid.Row Definitions>
                        <Row Definition Height="20"/>
                        <Row Definition Height="auto"/>
                        <Row Definition Height="auto"/>
                        <Row Definition Height="*"/>
                        <Row Definition Height="20"/>
                    </Grid.Row Definitions>

                    <!-- DB Connection-->
                <Group Box Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row Span="2" Grid.Column Span="2">
                        <Group Box.Header>
                            <Label Content="DB Connection"></Label>
                        </Group Box.Header>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Column="1">
                            <Grid.Row Definitions>
                                <Row Definition Height="Auto"/>
                                <Row Definition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.Row Definitions>
                            <Grid.Column Definitions>
                                <Column Definition Width="Auto"/>
                                <Column Definition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.Column Definitions>

                            <Text Block Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Font Size="15" Text="DB Context : " Margin="5"/>
                            <Text Box x:Name="Db Context" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Width="300" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Group Box>                               
                </Grid>
            </Tab Item>
```

Comment: Grid.Column and Grid.Row starts from 0. make it `<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Connection">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions >

                <!-- DB Connection-->
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        <Label Content="DB Connection"></Label>
                    </GroupBox.Header >
                    <Grid Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15" Text="DB Context : " Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Margin="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox >                               
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```